# How to use HTML tag in Email Body in android or to bold Title of body?

Tags: android, email

I am trying to sending mail by using following code. I want to make my title and text bold, I use HTML tag but its dot working, can any one help? I also want to make b date at the center of screen in body.

```
Intent msg = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
String[] address = new String[] { "" };
msg.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, address);
String subject = "";        
subject = "iVillage: "+storyTitle;
msg.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);

// This next line puts in the body of the message
String[] Content = new String[] { "HEllo There" };
msg.setType("text/html");
msg.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "<b><i>"+storyTitle+" \n\n "+storyPubDate+"</b></i> \n\n"+storyURL+"\n\n...\nSent From from Android");
startActivity(msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

What i Find in you code is like you started <b> tag first and then started <i> tag. After that you closed </b> first and then closed </i> tag. Just for sake try closing </i> tag first and then </b> tag. Or other way is:
You can use below code to send emails..

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("text/html");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "This is subject.");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "<b><i>"+storyTitle+"</i></b><br><br><b><i>"+"storyPubDate"+"</i></b><br>"+storyURL);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Share"));
```