# Bolding of the word in email intent does not work

Tags: android, email, fonts, bold

I want to bold some of the words in a string, then pass the string to the email intent to send  it. Apparantly, it won't work. I am using the Html.fromHtml. Please help! Following is the related class code.

```
final Spanned messageEmail = Html.fromHtml("Dear " + name + ",<br><br>" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <b>your payslip number is</b> " + payslipno +" and your net salary for the period "
                        + startofpayslip + " till " + 
                                  endofpayslip + " is "+  netsalary + " and it is issused on " + issuedate + ". According to the agreed overtime rate of " + agreedovertimerate + 
                                  " from " + startofovertimeperiod + " till " + endofovertimeperiod +  ", your net salary is calculated by adding your basic salary of " +
                                    basicsalary + " to your available allowance of " + typeofallowance + " of " + allowanceamt + " on " + allowancedate + ", " +
                                                "and any other extra payment of" + extrapayment + " and deducting from " + typeofdeduction 
                                            + " of " + deductionamt + " on " + deductiondate + ". Your availabe allowance for this month is "
                                            + availableallowance + ".") ;

                                    Log.i("Send email", "");

                        String[] TO = {email};
                        String[] CC = {""};
                        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                        emailIntent.setType("text/html");


                        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
                        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
                        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Payslip for period " + startofpayslip + " till " + endofpayslip);
                        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.toHtml(messageEmail));

                        try {
                               startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
                               Log.i("Finished sending email...", "");
                            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                               Toast.makeText(EmployeePaySlip.this, 
                               "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

The result of the text message will be like <p> dir = "ltr> Dear Mary, </p> <p dir="ltr">&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160; <b> your payslip number is </br> and so on and so for...
```

May i know what am i missing here? I tried removing the Html.fromHtml, the message will be normal, but the fonts will not be bold. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: I think you must pass your String (not Spanned) AS IS to your eMail BODY.

Comment: i cant, it will have error. Type mismatch: cannot convert from Spanned to String

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear: **String eMailMEssage = "Dear " + name + ",<br><br>" + ... + availableallowance + "."**

Comment: yeah i understand, but there is this error Type mismatch: cannot convert from Spanned to String. So i'm forced to used spanned.

Comment: Okay, perhaps now i understand your statement. If i were to put it as String, i will have to remove the Html.fromHtml, and the result will be normal, but the fonts will still not be bold.

Comment: They will be formatted in the body of your eMail client, since it will accept HTML formatted text.

Comment: I tried, it wasnt. The font still wasn't bold.

Comment: See the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303375/how-to-use-html-tag-in-email-body-in-android-or-to-bold-title-of-body)...

Comment: Well, i tried. The bold font <b>bold font</br> did not work. <br> works though.

Comment: Now I'm curious: what happens on the receiver side? does it arrive with or without bold? (I guess that <b>...</br> is a typo).

Comment: It arrives without bold.

Comment: Funny. I thought that at least the receiver would format the html correctly. So... it seems that you can only use <br/>.

Comment: Yeah, apparently it is.

Comment: What if  this line: **emailIntent.setType("text/html");** was so: **emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");**?